# vb express / visual studio - is it possible to run / debug one form only in a multi form application?

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I have a vb application consisting of several winForms and code files. Is it possible to run / debug only one form without having to run the whole application?

To be more specific, one of the forms in my application is the settings form where the user sets his/her desired options. These options are read/written to an xml file. Is it possible to debug just this one form (and not the whole program) to see if the reading/writing went well, if everything displayed correctly... ?

If I am thinking the wrong way about this, could you point me in the right direction?

By the way, I am using visual basic express / visual studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just change your project's startup form so that form gets loaded first.  Saves you from having to click the button to show the form, small savings though.  Project + Properties, Application tab, change the "Startup form" setting.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. It is a huge saving for me as my current startup form goes on a jihad and does many things in the background beside running two parallel processes. that's why I wanted to run this single form without going through all that.